# Print and Print Preview doesn't pull through CSS Stylehseet

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am trying to print only a section of my web page which is to be an invoice.
I am using the following Javascript code to open a new window and only add the content that I require.

IE: Bootstrap, Website Stylesheet.

```
function print_element(elem,event,$elementid){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(elem).hide();
    var prtContent = document.getElementById($elementid);
    var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width='+window.screen.width+',height='+window.screen.height+',toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');

    WinPrint.document.write($("head").html());
    WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);

    $("script").each(function(index){
        var src = $(this).attr("src");
        WinPrint.document.write("<script src='"+src+"'></script>");
    })

    WinPrint.document.close();
    WinPrint.focus();
    WinPrint.document.ready = function(){
        WinPrint.print();
        //WinPrint.close();
    }
    $(elem).show();
}
```

When the window opens, every thing is styled correctly without any issues, but when the print dialog shows, then all the text is in Black and White. It also prints in Black and white.

I have tried adding a colorful image. The image showed in full color. I then pasted the code from the CSS file the window directly, and it still printed in Black and White.

I also tried styling elements directly using both the `style` attribute and the `<font>` tags with no avail.

This is not a printer issue. I checked, the website does exactly the same on multiple computers and printers.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Your HTML is pretty mangled up (you're `document.write`ing everything, so it will contain contents of `head`, your content, and then the scripts) - perhaps that's the issue?

Comment: Show the HTML and CSS that is actually being printed, not the javascript that generates that HTML by grabbing portions of a document we can't see.

Comment: @eithedog - I know that it will have the content from the `head`, the element and the script, the thing is that the invoice being printed needs to look exactly like it does on the front end. That is why I import all the scripts and Stylesheets, so that it can replicate the same effect on the printed screen

Comment: @DanielBeck I've tried to paste the code from the webpage into my answer and also into JS Fiddle and HTML Fiddle and none of them are working, the reason is because my code relies on files on the server (IE: Fonts that are not available online). I could post the HTML for the print screen into a fiddle if it would help.

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer can you please do that (post it to fiddle / pastebin)

Comment: @eithedog I have added the code from the Print Window popup to paste bin here: http://pastebin.com/SaBW9e7B